# ng-cloak in angularjs does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to hide webpage content as long as the page is not fully loaded. Therefore I use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
       <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

a view that I include:

```
<div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <hr/>
    <p>this is a {{controller.test}}</p>
</div>
```

Result: when I load the page I still see the content rendering before the replacement was applied. What might I be missing?

Comment: Is library loaded in `<head>` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I have the angularjs lib in the `<body>` tag as follows: `<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @Satpal also when I only use `ng-cloak` without the class, the directive seems not to be applied.

Comment: `<style>` tag is added by you manually or it is being created by `angular` ?

Comment: Is it possible at all to let the style tag being created by angular? At least I added it myself to the index.html, see updated example above.

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle ? That would give us more idea!

Comment: According to the docs - `For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application.` Try doing this

Comment: I would also guess that since you are using `ng-cloak` on an angular template, and not on the parent page, angular has to already be loaded for it to load the template that you are wanting to hide in the first place.  Can you just add `ng-cloak` to an element on your parent page like: `<div class="container" ng-cloak>`

Comment: Great, these both answers in combination worked.